# Wine/Orbiter Performance Issues on Kubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wine, kubuntu

I downloaded the Orbiter spaceflight simulator (build 100830) from the official website. When running Orbiter, I get ~1 FPS, and it maxes out one of my CPU's cores (I have an i5). I run Orbiter by "wine orbiter.exe". All dependencies are satisfied. Wine is V1.6.2. It was working fine on Arch Linux, but I upgraded to Kubuntu 14.04 LTS, and had to reinstall my programs. The video settings which previously yielded an acceptable framerate (~20-30, depending on scenery) now have me at around 1 FPS. Any ideas?

Xenoth

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but try setting the default program to open exes to wine windows program loader, and then click on it. If you're using the terminal, it might make orbiter lag, although I don't know why it would do that.

Comment: That doesn't affect it, I'm afraid. The same performance issues are present when run from a terminal or with kdeinit (I think that's what right click->open with uses?)

Comment: You should add the version of wine you have